# MongoDB manually preparing for upstart but not running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, mongodb

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Instead of using the system provided MongoDB which is 2.4, I want to use 2.6 so I downloaded MongoDB executable and just put it in the places I wanted. Then I mostly copied the upstart script comes with the 2.4 package:

```
description "MongoDB"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

limit nofile 64000 64000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /data/db/
end script

script
    ENABLE_MONGODB="yes"
    if [ -f /etc/default/mongodb ]; then
        . /etc/default/mongodb
    fi
    if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "xyes" ]; then
        exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid mongodb \
            --exec /usr/local/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb.conf
    fi
end script
```

When I run manually like so:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

It runs just fine.

But when I use `sudo start mongodb` the process probably dies out as I was not able to see it in `ps -ef`. The upstart log doesn't say much (/var/log/upstart/mongodb.log):

```
warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you did this:

> Instead of using the system provided MongoDB which is 2.4, I want to
>   use 2.6 so I downloaded MongoDB executable and just put it in the
>   places I wanted.

That’s really not the supported and recommended way you should be installing MongoDB on your system. The MongoDB team is very well aware that official Linux repositories don’t always keep up to date with latest releases of many packages, so [they provide their own PPA for MongoDB as explained here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). I would recommend removing whatever you just installed and follow these steps instead.

First, import the public key used by the package management system:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Then create a sources list file for MongoDB:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Now run `apt-get` with `update` to refresh the sources list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally, install MongoDB directly from the repository like this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: Oh that's great! I'll use that instead. Do you have any idea how to check how that upstart mongodb dies on me?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll accept your answer in two minutes since the system won't allow it right now.

Comment: Psst!  Notice that the command being run, and receiving the `--`, is `start-stop-daemon`.  Think about how one stops `--config` from being interpreted as an option by _that_ command.  I just had to deal with this at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187540/5132 .